# When is $14k^4 - 6k^2 + 1$ a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-mathematics, square-numbers

Is there some sophisticated method (or maybe some easy one, though I doubt it) to show that the only solution to $m^2 = 14k^4 - 6k^2 + 1$ in positive integers is $k=1$, $m=3$? Perhaps something around elliptic curves and SAGE computation or whatever seems fine, though the simplest attack will be most appreciated!

When trying this out by hand, the best idea I had what to write it like $m^2 - 14(k^2 - \mbox{something})^2 = \mbox{something}$ and then consider this Pell-type equation, but the presence of $k^2$ in one of the Pell variables makes things much harder.

Comment: The polynomic $14k^4-6k^2-8$ has 1 as double solution.

Comment: Well the RHS is always $0\bmod 3$ if $k\not\equiv 0\bmod 3$ so $m$ needs be a multiple of $3$ in those cases...

Comment: For transforming quartics to elliptic curves, see [Birational Equivalence of Diophantine Equations and Elliptic Curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1592599/318073) (which was a follow up to a similar question [Quartic diophantine equation: $16r^4+112r^3+200r^2-112r+16=s^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1561877/318073)). There is also a Magma function for integral points on a quartic, see [Diophantine equation $7b^2+7b+7=a^4$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2080009/318073).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$m^2=14k^4-6k^2+1\tag{1}$$

An equation $(1)$ is birationally equivalent to the elliptic curve
$$Y^2 = X^3 - 68X + 208\tag{2}$$
with $$k = \frac{2X-8}{Y}, m = \frac{X^3-12X^2-144+68X}{Y^2}$$

According to [LMFDB](https://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/4480/f/1) , elliptic curve has seven integer points as follows.

$(-6,\pm 20)$, $ \left(4, 0\right) $, $(6,\pm 4)$, $(13,\pm 39).$

Hence we get the positive integer solution $(k,m)=(1,3)$ from $(X,Y)=(6,\pm 4).$

Comment: I like this approach, but there is one thing I do not understand. You seem to implicitly use that *if* $(k,m)$ is an integral point on $(1)$ *then* there is an integral point $(X,Y)$ on $(2)$ such that
$$k = \frac{2X-8}{Y}, m = \frac{X^3-12X^2-144+68X}{Y^2}.$$
Can you explain why this is true? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: In order for $(k,m)$ to be an integer, at least $(X,Y)$ must be an integer.

Comment: That is exactly my question; *why* must $X$ and $Y$ be integers? I see that if $(X,Y)$ is a rational point on $(2)$ with $X\neq4$ then
$$m=\frac{X^3-12X^2+68X-144}{X^3-68X+208}=\frac{X^2-8X+36}{X^2+4X-52},$$
and hence for $n:=1-m$ we have
$$nX^2+4(n-3)X+4(22-13n)=0,$$
which means $X=\tfrac{a}{b}$ for integers $a$ and $b$ with $a\mid4(22-13n)$ and $b\mid n$. But I do not see why $X$ must be integral, i.e. why we can take

Comment: In general, since rational points $(X,Y)$ increase rapidly, we can't much expect the integer solution from rational points $(X,Y).$  
For instance, $(X,Y)=(13 , 39 ),(918/49 , 25460/343 ),(34537/6084 , 1052117/474552 ),(28276086/78961 , 150319301164/22188041 ).$  
Substitute $(X,Y)=(\frac{b}{a^2},\frac{c}{a^3})$ to $k=\frac{2X-8}{Y}$, then $k=\frac{2(a-4c^2)c}{b}.$  
Thus, though we may get the integer points $k$ using small rational points $(X,Y)$, we can't get it for this problem.

Comment: BTW, there is a case that integer points of quartic are derived from Mordell-Weil group below.  
It's similar to this problem.
(https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3389407/a-diophantine-equation-related-to-arithmetic-progression-t-n-anbncn/3397172#3397172)